# CSS, HTML, как выбрать селектор обычного текста?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Как обратиться в CSS к тексту "Как это выбрать???" идущего после первого li?
Хром нас уверяет - никак: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Как это выбрать???
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Текст 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: никак, используйте javascript

Comment: а не лутше в `span` обернуть текст и уже к нему обращатся?

Comment: @NickolayRudak, подскажите каким что именно использовать в javascript'е?

Comment: @klifort, нет, я на стороне клиента.

Comment: Вообще ничего не понял....)))

Comment: За чем в `css` обращаться к тексту?

Comment: @Air, чтобы стилей накидать)
На сервере стоит yii2 и выводит массив в меню через виджет, и я не разобрался как заставить его оборачивать первый уровень меню в теги -> поэтому решил костыльей накидать))

Comment: ну стили пишутся для элемента, а не теста внутри...)

Comment: @Air, всё верно! Поэтому и превращаем через костыли внутренний текст в элементы))

Comment: Это я уже понял, просто когда я писал `первый коммент` к этому вопросу, я этого не понял )))  Лучше правь вопрос, чтобы было сразу понятно...

Comment: @Air, понял принял!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var li = $('.menu > li')
var node = li.contents().filter(function() {
 return this.nodeType === 3; // выбираем ноду
})
node.first().wrap('<span class="newSpan"/>') // оборачиваем в span с классом который задаёт нужные нам стили
```

```css
.newSpan{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Как это выбрать???
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Текст 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Текст 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!